# How can I convert a function to a module in RequireJS in a simplistic way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, require, requirejs-define

I have been reading the documentation, but I can't seem to do this in an easy way. I think I confuse this too much with `node.js` which uses the same words, e.g. `require`, `exports`, `module` etc.

Imagine a main script something like this. (And imagine the functions are complex)

```
require(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function($) {

    $("#staticButton").click(function() {
        showMessage('What does this button do?');
    });

    function showMessage(message) {
        alert(message);
    }

});
```

Now imagine I want to use `showMessage()` in multiple scripts. How do I actually do that?

In `Node.js` I would attach `showMessage()` to `exports.showMessage` inside `showMessage.js` and do something like this everywhere I want to use it:

```
require(['jquery', 'domReady!'], function($) {

    var showMessage = require('showMessage'); // Easy huh?

    $("#staticButton").click(function() {
        showMessage('What does this button do?');
    });

});
```

But with `RequireJS` this gives me the error that I first need to load it. Do I need to `require` or `define` this before I can use the above syntax?
Do I really need to add it in the main script `require` array? I don't like that. What if you have 20 functions?

```
require(['jquery', 'domReady!', func01, func02, (...) func20], function($, empty, func01, func02, (...) func20) {}
```

That's pure syntactic salt. I like the `Node.js` sugar way better:

```
var func01 = require(func01),
    func02 = require(func02),
    (...)
    func20 = require(func20);
```

I am confusing the two too much. Can someone explain how I simply put functions in external files and use them as simple as possible?

---

I'm assuming the module turned function needs to look like this:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
    return function(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
});
```

..but if that can be done easier, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try to think in terms of *modules*, functions are something more low-level in this context. You define *modules*, requiring them later returns their public "interface" as an object with some properties, which may happen to be functions.

What I found useful was a "static utils module" pattern:

**utils.js**

```
define(function () {
    return {
        showMessage: function (text) {
            alert(text);
        },
        foo: function () {
            alert('bar');
        }
    }
})
```

Or a simplified equivalent: (-> [docs](http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/api.html#defsimple))

**utils.js**

```
define({
    showMessage: function (text) {
        alert(text);
    },
    foo: function () {
        alert('bar');
    }
});
```

Then, inside your **main.js**:

```
define(['utils'], function (Utils) {
    Utils.showMessage('!');
})
```

If you end up with too many dependencies (that usually indicates your module is doing too much, by the way) you can use the [sugar syntax](http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/whyamd.html#sugar) instead:

```
define(function (require) {
    var Utils = require('utils');
    Utils.showMessage('!');
})
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I think that last example you do is closest to what I want. Combined with the docs you linked, I should start my dependency array with `['require', ...]` and the callback with `function(require, ...)` and from then on I can just `require` what I want, kinda like the `node` way I mentioned.

I've upvoted your answer and I will accept it if this turns out to be my solution!

Comment: I guess this makes `require('utils');` a static loader. Can I preload `'utils'`? If I `require('utils');` in 10 scripts, will it load `utils.js` 10 times? (If I am correct it will load only once, because according to the docs, `requirejs` will `internally convert the above define call into` the dependency array.

Comment: Yep, **1)** each module's body is only loaded/evaluated once regardless of how many times it's required, if you actually need the inverse behaviour make your module return a factory which returns a new instance of an object every time it's called. **2)** sugar is just that: sugar syntax; it uses regexes to expand it to the "full" form before evaluating module's body.

Comment: Thank you! I think they should start with simple basic examples like this in the docs because they are pretty long and boring. Best libraries start with a simple example that will convince users of it's value without prior knowledge.